# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Tags: c#, .net

I'm setting up a new project on my dev laptop and when I build the project from Visual Studio, everything goes as expected, but when I do from a powershell script, it returns this:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.CSharp.targets(316,9):
> error MSB4062: The "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildTasks.Csc" task could not be loaded from the assembly
> C:\disk_path\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.3.2\build..\tools\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CodeAnalysis.dll.
> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core,
> Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
> one of its dependencies.  The system cannot find the file specified.
> Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly
> and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a
> public class that implements  Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.
> [C:\disk_path\Code\Client.Models\Client.Models.csproj]
> C:\disk_path\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.3.2\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props(13,5):
> error :  Microsoft.Net.Compilers is only supported on MSBuild v14.0
> and above [C:\disk_path\Code\Client.Models\Client.Models.csproj]

The most frustrating thing is that my colleague that has exactly the same dev laptop (from prerequisites perspective), has no problem with it. Any hints that can help me sort this out are more than welcome.

*disk_path is not the actual name of the folder, but the path on the disk in which I have the code

Comment: Look like you target is Net 4.0 (v4.0.30319).  Is that correct?  Check you installed software in control panel and see what versions of Net are installed.  Compare to working machine.

Comment: I'll look and get back with an answer. Ty @jdweng

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to install MS VS 2017 (I had only VS2019 installed on my machine). That's it.

Answer (score 2):

Open the Visual Studio Installer (in VS 2019 you can open it from the Tools menu with the "Get Tools and Features..." option). Then choose to install the .NET development tools that you need. For example Microsoft.Build.Utilities v2.0 is in .NET 3.5, and Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core v14.0.0.0 is in .NET 4.0.

Different versions of Visual Studio will have various versions of the .NET SDK preinstalled.